# i am trying to delete messages eg: naukri. I am able to delete only 1st message not mutiple. I used loop but it's not working

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Actually I am trying to delete multiple messages using selenium webDriver.
I can able to delete 1 but not multiple because page is refreshing.

I tried using this Explicitly

```
WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver,40);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div/a[contains(., 'DELETE')]")));

//click on recruiter messages
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'Recruiter Messages')]")).click();

// click on Delete button

for(int i=0;i< 10;i++){
    WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver,40);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div/a[contains(., 'DELETE')]")));

    WebElement delete=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div/a[contains(., 'DELETE')]"));
    delete.click();

    //click on Delete button in Popup
    WebElement delectok=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='waves-effect waves-light btn-large blue-btn']"));
    delectok.click();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use wait until element is clickable.

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div/a[contains(., 'DELETE')]")));
```